# How to get a method to get and add new objects into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I only recently started to learn code so forgive me if this is trivial but I can't seem to figure it out, this is a simple assignment for class. Here my professor gave us this and told me to create the checkout class on my own. My question is how could I make the `enterItem` method in the checkout class to add the "rice" and "baguette" objects into an ArrayList?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Checkout checkout = new Checkout();

        checkout.enterItem(new Rice("Basmati Rice", 2.25, 399));
        checkout.enterItem(new Baguette("Wheat Baguette", 105));
```

This is kinda what I have tried but it does not work and I'm not sure why or how to make it work

```java
public class Checkout {
       
    ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
    
    public void enterItem(){
        items.add()
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Comment: Derive your foods from a common `Food` interface or abstract class and use the method like this: `public void enterItem(Food food) {items.add(food);}`

Comment: Does the array list in `Checkout` class need to be raw in your assignment?

Comment: "Does the array list in Checkout class need to be raw in your assignment?" - @AlexRudenko What does it mean to you for a class to be "raw"?

Answer (score 1):

```
checkout.enterItem(new Rice("Basmati Rice", 2.25, 399));
```

That code is invoking the `enterItem` method and passing a `Rice` as an argument.

```
public void enterItem(){
    items.add()
}
```

The `enterItem` method does not accept any arguments, so that won't work.  You could do this...

```
public void enterItem(Rice rice){
    items.add(rice);
}
```

That will work for `Rice`, but not for `Baguette`  (unless `Baguette` extends `Rice`).  You could add 2 versions of `enterItem`:

```
public void enterItem(Rice rice){
    items.add(rice);
}

public void enterItem(Baguette bag){
    items.add(bag);
}
```

If `Rice` and `Bagquette` share something above them in the inheritance/implements hierarchy, something like this could work:

```
public class Baguette implements Edible {}


public class Rice implements Edible {}


public void enterItem(Edible edible){
    items.add(edible);
}
```